# maximum bound for edges in graph $G$ if we want shortest cycle stay at $k$

Tags: graphs, upper-bound

In a simple graph $G$, what is the maximum bound for edges if we want shortest cycle stay at $k$.

How we can find this bound for a graph? Have it any formula or technique to calculate it?

thanks in advance

Comment: This seems to be a problem of extremal combinatorics; I don't see any computational aspect to the question.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps you should ask at Mathematics.SE.